# How to count the records in a Sqlite table that match a date restriction?

Tags: android, sqlite, date, android-cursorloader

I'm using a CursorLoader to return a record count from my Content Provider, and I need to count only those records that are 7 or fewer days old. My attempts to make this work have so far yielded nothing but frustration, as the count is **always** zero. I have limited experience with Sqlite and CursorLoaders, and I suspect I'm making a very simple error . Here is my code:

```
String strCriteria = "SELECT julianday('now') - julianday('" + Session.DATE_STRING
            + "','gregorian') <8";

return new CursorLoader(getSherlockActivity(), Session.CONTENT_URI, 
           new String[] {"count(" + Session.TABLE_NAME + "." + Session._ID +") AS Count " }, 
          strCriteria, null,null);
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

I should add that the DATE_STRING column stores the date as a string in the yyyy-MM-dd format. I do actually have another column storing date as a long, but I haven't figured out how to do Sqlite date queries using numeric values either.

UPDATE to question: if I replace the Session.DATE_STRING part of the strCriteria definition with a text date, it all works perfectly. For example, if I use the following code :

```
String strCriteria = "SELECT julianday('now') - julianday('" + "2013-05-08"
            + "','gregorian') <8";
```

...instead of what I've got above, then it all works perfectly. This leads me to believe that my code is not actually putting the **value** of the Session.DATE_STRING column into the string, but rather something else, most likely the actual string name of the column. I do not know how to get around this, as I was assuming that the query would actually fill in the proper data value at runtime. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT WITH SOLUTION: I've figured out how to make it work properly. It's quite simple really - I had to remove the ' from around Session.DATE_STRING to ensure that the value of the column was inserted, rather than the column name. So, this is how the strCriteria needed to be defined:

```
String strCriteria = "SELECT julianday('now') - julianday(" + Session.DATE_STRING
            + ",'gregorian') <8";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for what you intend, but I do have a cache cleaner in my app that clears any record from the database that could have been stored more than x days ago.

**Step One**: When saving each record, I save the date as millis. Keep in mind, I also save the date as String, since I use that for labeling and other stuff too.

**Ste Two**: Create the Where statement:

```
String where = DbOpenHelper.SAVED_ON + " <= " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - msBackInTime);
```

Where `msBackInTime` is the amount of days in millis that i want to delete. For instance, if I want to go three days back and erase, then msBackInTime would be: 259200000. That way, the query would return any items that are less (and therefore mean they were stored **before**) than the date supplied as a result.

Quick example:

Right now is: 1368020762363 in millis.
Three days in millis is: 259200000
Three days ago is: Right now (1368020762363) minus three days (259200000).

Ergo, anything with a `SAVED_ON` value lower than the result of the difference is what I'll get in the query.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Daniel, that approach has some merit, but would also potentially cause the results to not be completely correct. 5 days = 432000000 milliseconds. If I ran the query at 3pm, it would "miss" records entered in 7 days ago at 9am since those records would be more than 432000000 milliseconds ago, although from a "date" point of view they should be returned. Having said that, I may have to resort to this approach if I cannot sort this out properly.

Comment: I tried to find more appropriate ways to go, but couldn't really figure anything out with the Strings of text, if you do figure something else out keep me posted